# Global Function from framework gives Undefined symbols linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode7.2

I am trying to use a framework in my app ([CoreBitcoin](https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin)). Followed the build instructions from the README and copied the framework directory into my project. I also linked it in the Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

Now the code compiles and works

```
#import <CoreBitcoin/CoreBitcoin.h>

// I can instantiate class objects and use functions such as 
BTCKey *newKey = [[BTCKey alloc] init];
[newKey setPublicKey: nil];
```

But if I try to use any global function such as

```
BTCDataFromBase58(@"anystring");
```

The linker throws an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"BTCDataFromBase58(NSString*)"
```

I have looked around and tried many solutions to fix this error: the framework is in my search paths, I disabled bitcode and fiddled a bunch with the project build settings, however, it is strange that the undefined symbols are specific to global functions.

I am using Xcode 7.2, and get the warning:

```
(CoreBitcoin library path) was built for newer iOS version (9.2) than being linked (7.1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843900/xcode-7-warnings-object-file-was-built-for-newer-ios-version-than-being-linked

Comment: The other question is only getting compiler warnings whereas I am getting an error that is failing the build.

Comment: Add i386 architecture and try again

Comment: Tried adding i386 to valid architecture under build settings but still got the same error.