# Object file was built for newer version than being linked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deployment

does anyone know how to fix this? I've checked my pod file as well as my pod deployment target, both are set to 9.0 as well. I'm really new to Xcode and I want this app to be available at 9.0 and later. The whole project was initially at 10.3. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: You're missing some pertinent details. First, I'll assume you've tested things to a point that you pod file isn't needed *and* it works on a IOS 9 device. So, next, what does this pod file actually do? And looking at your question, third, does it work in 10.3? Have you backed it down to 10.0, 9.x, etc.?

Comment: I think this is answered in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843900/xcode-7-warnings-object-file-was-built-for-newer-ios-version-than-being-linked